# ag-grid - How can custom an specific groupRow renderer with multiple row groups

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a table with more than 4 nested rowgroups, I want to indicate `supressCount=true` and custom width just in two of them but `autoGroupColumnDef` prop of `AgGridReact` component applies to all rowgroups:

```
<AgGridReact
          gridOptions={gridOptions}
          context={context}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          rowData={plainRows}
          groupDefaultExpanded={0}
          groupDisplayType='multipleColumns'
          autoGroupColumnDef={{
            headerValueGetter: params => `${params.colDef.headerName}`,
            filterValueGetter: (params) => {
              if (params.node) {
                var colGettingGrouped = params.colDef.showRowGroup + '';
                return params.api.getValue(colGettingGrouped, params.node);
              }
            },
            minWidth: 220
          }}
          modules={[...AllEnterpriseModules, ...specificModules]}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
/>
```

My column definition examples for two of them:

```
 const getColumnDefs = () => {
  return [
  {
    headerName: 'Group row 1',
    field: 'field1',
    width: 350,
    minWidth: 100,
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
    },
    {
    headerName: 'Group row 2',
    field: 'field2',
    width: 320,
    minWidth: 250,
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
     },.....
```

These are my versions:

```
 "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "27.1.0",
 "@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^27.1.0",
 "@ag-grid-community/core": "^27.1.0",
 "@ag-grid-community/react": "^27.1.0",
 "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^27.1.0",
 "@ag-grid-enterprise/core": "^27.1.0",
 "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping": "^27.1.0",
 "ag-grid": "^18.1.0",
 "ag-grid-react": "^18.1.0",
```

And these my imports:

```
 import {AgGridReact} from '@ag-grid-community/react';
 import {AllEnterpriseModules} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
 import {ClientSideRowModelModule} from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
 import {RowGroupingModule} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping';
```

Any ideas?

Adding `supressCount=true` to `autoGroupColumnDef` affects all rowgroup columns.

I tried adding `cellRenderer` and `cellREndererParams` attributes to `columnDefs` json to an specific column but does not work.
I deletted this `autoGroupColumnDef` prop but even `minWIdth` param does not applies in columns.